# WCF - how to create multiple elements in request with same name

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, web, service

I need to implement web service to create request on client side. Multiple Esc elements should be at the same level with other different elements. If I use list it creates list of elements under Escs. Any help is appreciated.

[image: XML request]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XNamespace ns = "abc";
            XElement request = new XElement(ns + "Request", new object[] {
               new XElement(ns + "Cont"),
               new XElement(ns + "Lea"),
               new XElement(ns + "Deal"),
               new XElement(ns + "Esc"),
               new XElement(ns + "Esc"),
               new XElement(ns + "Esc"),
               new XElement(ns + "Esc"),
               new XElement(ns + "Esc"),
               new XElement(ns + "Part"),
               new XElement(ns + "Veh")
            });
        }
    }
}
```